# android Json content shows only one attibute

Tags: android, json

I have developed up to the level where one attribute is shown in the list view, but I want to show all the attributes in http://hopscriber.com/log.php .

```
[
    {
        "uname": "test",
        "pwd": "test"
    },
    {
        "uname": "faith",
        "pwd": "3220"
    },
    {
        "uname": "losh",
        "pwd": "wick"
    },
    {
        "uname": "loshi",
        "pwd": "wick"
    }
]
```

The following is my code and it only shows the result of pwd.

```
public class Menu extends Activity {

    TextView result;
    Intent intent;

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_Name = null;
    private static final String TAG_Pass = null;

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        // Name of the User
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        intent = getIntent();
        String Naming = intent.getStringExtra("name1");
        result.setText("Hey " + Naming);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        try {
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 0);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

            // prepare the HTTP GET call
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://hopscriber.com/log.php");
            // get the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = httpClient.execute(httpget).getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                // get the response content as a string
                String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                // consume the entity
                entity.consumeContent();

                // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed, shut down the
                // connection manager to ensure immediate deallocation of all
                // system resources
                httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

                // return the JSON response
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                if (jsonArray != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put(TAG_Name, object.getString("uname"));
                        map.put(TAG_Pass, object.getString("pwd"));

                        contactList.add(map);

                    }
                }

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                        R.layout.menu_list_row, new String[] { TAG_Name,
                                TAG_Pass }, new int[] { R.id.LR_Name,
                                R.id.LR_date });
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Booyah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your json node names.

For example:

```
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_Name = "name";
private static final String TAG_Pass = "pwd";
```

Doing so will output the desired results.